# Responsive Primefaces galllery

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to make a Primefaces **< p:gallery >** responsive in order that pictures inside **keep their aspect ratio** (to make it clear: I wish the same behaviour that a simple IMG with width:100%, it increases/decreases its height automatically in order to keep its aspect ratio).

The resulting HTML elements rendered when a gallery is used are the following:

```
<div class"pictures_gallery">
    <ul class"ui-galleria-panel-wrapper">
        <li class"ui-galleria-panel">
            <img class"a_picture"/>
        </li>
        /*one extra "li" for each picture*/
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS I'm applying right now:

```
.pictures_gallery{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
}

.ui-galleria-panel-wrapper{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important
}

.ui-galleria-panel{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
}

.a_picture{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
}
```

My problem is that gallery is not inside a container with a defined height and the resulting gallery height is ZERO.
How can I achieve the desired result? Is it possible?

Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: don't blame me for the **!important**, it's used just to simplify...

Comment: Try with: `img {display:block;max-width:100%;max-height:100vh}`

Comment: Then why don't you (try to) put it in a container with a defined height and width? And yes, suggestion by @Vxp is creative too

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answer!
Sorry VXp, but your code doesn't work, I forgot to detail that the gallery has a default width and height that need to be overwritten. In any case I don't see the logic in your code.
Kukeltje, I don't specify any height because I need it to work for many resolutions and, if I specify one, the pictures lost their aspect ratio when resized.
I'm just searching for the same default behaviour that a standard graphicImage has...

Comment: The main problem I see is that even if I specify a specific height for the picture ( for example width: 100% and height: 400px), the rest of containers (DIV, UL and LI) doesn't resize (all of them with height: auto). Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Any clue???????